# Nginx can't proxy pass between two server blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I want to set up reverse proxy for two services I have on the same machine. One is a rails service running on port 3000 and the other is a nodejs service running on port 4000. I also want to have `https` using letsencrypt and certbot

The scenario is simple:

1. Any `http` request should be redirected to `https`
2. Any request to `https://api.mydomain.com` should be passed to node service running on port 4000 (nodejs)
3. Any request to `https://api.mydomain.com/api` (and /admin & /assets) should be passed to rails service running on port 3000

Here is the nginx code I already have. I didn't touch the default configs for nginx, but modified the default file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.mydomain.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    client_max_body_size 11m;
    client_header_timeout 1m;
    client_body_timeout 1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 1m;
    proxy_send_timeout 1m;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass api.mydomain.com:3000$request_uri;
    }
    location /admin {
        proxy_pass api.mydomain.com:3000$request_uri;
    }
    location /assets {
        proxy_pass api.mydomain.com:3000$request_uri;
    }

}


server {
    listen 3000 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:3000 ssl http2;
    server_name api.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    client_max_body_size 11m;
    client_header_timeout 1m;
    client_body_timeout 1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 1m;
    proxy_send_timeout 1m;


    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/ruby;
    root /var/www/MyDomain-BackEnd/current/public;
    access_log /var/www/MyDomain-BackEnd/current/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/MyDomain-BackEnd/current/log/production.log;
}
```

I get a timeout error when trying to access any route like `https://api.mydomain.com/api`, but using port numbers with the requests works fine (e.g. `https://api.mydomain.com:3000/api`.

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: @RichardSmith tested, still getting error

Comment: I didn't notice that port 3000 was using SSL. If that's the intention, use: `proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;`

Comment: @RichardSmith tested, no luck :(

Comment: your server is configured to use port 3000, you need to configure for port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS without passing the ports as part of the URL

Comment: @RafaelZerbini so do you mean I have to remove the last server block? what modifications I have to do?